# MATLAB: Resizing a figure properly

Tags: pdf, matlab, resize, export, figure

I have a figure that I would like to resize and afterwards print as a PDF.
Using something like

```
set(hFig, 'PaperUnits', 'centimeters')
set(hFig, 'PaperSize', [x_B x_H]);
```

works as long as I do not resize the figure too drastically. If I reduce the height then at some points the xlabel moves out of the figure. I have searched a lot but only found an solution to manually resize the underlying axes-object

```
scalefactor = 0.96;
movefactor = 0.82;
hAx = get(gcf,'CurrentAxes');
g = get(hAx,'Position');
% 1=left, 2=bottom, 3=width, 4=height
g(2) = g(2) + (1-movefactor)/2*g(4);
g(4) = scalefactor*g(4);
set(hAx,'Position',g);
```

I do not like this approach since I have to manually adjust the two factors.

Before printing I set the 'interpreter' to 'latex' of all text-objects (if that is of concern).
Printing is achieved using

```
print(hFig, '-dpdf', '-loose', 'test.pdf');
```

I hoped to loosen the bounding box by using '-loose'. Any help is highly appreciated!

edit:
It seems that really the interpreter (none, tex, latex) plays a role in this. I got inspired by this post here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150802/how-to-save-plot-into-pdf-without-large-margin-around) and came up with this solution:

```
tightInset = get(gca, 'TightInset');
position(1) = tightInset(1);

position(3) = 1 - tightInset(1) - tightInset(3);
if strcmpi(x_Interpreter,'latex')
    position(2) = tightInset(2)+ 1*tightInset(4);
    position(4) = 1 - tightInset(2) - 2*tightInset(4);
else
    position(2) = tightInset(2)+ 0*tightInset(4);
    position(4) = 1 - tightInset(2) - 1*tightInset(4);
end
set(gca, 'Position', position);
```

Comment: Could you post a minimal non-working example so that we can reproduce your error?

Comment: Have you tried resizing the figure first and then setting up axes etc.?

Comment: It is worth noting that the behaviour of the "print" command can be dependent on your display resolution settings (at least on some versions of MATLAB under Windows). This is especially apparent when trying to print large images. When I am preparing figures for print/export, I tend to specify the sizes explicitly to avoid headaches.

Answer (score 1):

This may not solve your problem completely (it may just help clean up your code), but I found the [fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30736-fig-the-exact-figure-size-and-no-white-space) code in the file exchange to be helpful: it lets you easily set the exact size of figures without bordering white space.