# matlab: plot area continues after data ends

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, figure

I have a simple plot in Matlab but as you can see from the screenshot. There is a lot of white space on the right side of the graph after the end of the data series.

[image]

Any idea how to get rid of this white space and make the plot go right to the edge of the figure? Here is my code:

```
Plotx = plot(x);
hold on
PlotState = plot(Y);

set(Plotx,'Color','black','LineWidth',2.5);
set(PlotState,'Color','red','LineWidth',2.5);

set(gca, 'XTick',(1:3:62))
labels = time;
set(gca,'XTickLabel',labels(1:3:62))

grid on
```

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5152611/14946) shows how to remove the border on any side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I manually adjust the limit of the `x`-axis, using:

```
set(gca,'XLim',[0 63])
```

Answer (score 4):

This usually works for me:

```
axis tight;
xlim('auto');
```

You must select your figure, go back to the console and use those commands so they affect the last active figure.

EDIT: The above line should automatically make your graph axis very tight on your data. For more fine control, you may want to [define the axis limits manually](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/setting-axis-parameters.html):

```
 axis([xmin,xmax,ymin,ymax])
```