# WYSIWYG for Matlab export_fig

Tags: pdf, export, matlab-figure

I have several matlab figure I want to convert to pdf format for publication. I'm using the `export_fig(gcf,'test.pdf','-transparent')` command line, but the output pdf is different from the original figure (axes label, text box, anotations,... moved from their initial position).

Have you any idea how to get a WYSIWYG output ? Thanks !

Comment: Print Screen, or the actual 'save' button (the one with the floppy disk) on the figure GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way, but it have to be done manualy :

- open the .fig file
- select file > print preview
- if the graph is too large, select format "A3" and orientation "landscape"
- then "print"

For Latex, this orientation can causes some problems (even by using the `trim ={. . . .},clip` function in `includegraphics`), that is why I use the pdf rotation website : https://www.rotatepdf.net/

Hope it could be usefull, because NO NEED for more matlab function or code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
saveas(gcf, 'test.pdf', 'pdf')
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3801730/get-rid-of-the-white-space-around-matlab-figures-pdf-output) for removing the whitespace which MATLAB will put around.

If you want to avoid this, just save the figure as *.eps vector image. You can also include *.eps images in your latex publication.

```
saveas(gcf, 'test.eps', 'epsc')
```